# Variable optimized to zero

Tags: c++, g++

In the following program, the `out` variable always prints as `0` if it is compiled with optimization above `O1`. The `out` variable prints correctly with any level of optimizaiton if I uncomment the `cout` line in the `digitTruncate` function.

Am I doing something that is "undefined", or is this a compiler issue?

```
#include <iostream>
#include "mytime.hpp"
#include <stdint.h>

template <class IN>
int32_t
digitTruncate (IN data_in, uint32_t digits, uint64_t* data_out,
               int32_t bits = -1, bool safe = false)
{
  if (bits == -1)
    bits = (digits / 0.3010299957) + 1;
  if (!safe) 
  {
    if (bits > (int32_t)sizeof(data_in) * 8)
      return -1;
  }
  *data_out = (data_in & (0xffffffffffffffff >> (64 - bits)));
  //std::cout << *data_out << std::endl;
  return (bits / 8) + 1;
}

int
main()
{
  uint64_t cycles1, cycles2;
  uint32_t out;
  char* block = new char[8];
  cycles1 = mytime::cycles();
  for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
  {
    uint32_t init = (uint32_t)mytime::cycles();
    digitTruncate(init, 5, ((uint64_t*)block), 17, true);
    out = *((uint32_t*)block);
  }
  cycles2 = mytime::cycles();
  std::cout << cycles2 - cycles1 << std::endl;
  std::cout << "results: " << out << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't think it is a compiler issue, I was listing possibilities.

Comment: @Mysticial Why would commenting out the the `cout` line prevent writing to `block`? That is an entirely different line. The code above is in the "commented state".

Comment: @chewsocks Whoops, I misread your question as commenting out the `digitTruncate`. My bad.

Comment: You are working with block as an uint64_t in the function, but as an uint32_t in main. What CPU are you using? Some (very rare) CPUs have perverse integer formats.

Comment: I suspect there might be something funny going on with strict-aliasing here.

Comment: @Muscles It is one from the AMD FX6000 series. The reason I'm working with `uint64_t` for calculations is that that is the largest the output will ever be, but for this case I knew the final output would fit in 32 bits, that is why I cast it to a `uint32_t`.

Comment: Why declare `block` as `char* block = new char[8];` instead of just a `uint64_t`?

Comment: What happens if you declare `block` as `uint64_t` and then `memcpy` the first 4 bytes of that into `out` after calling `digitTruncate()`? Also, I can't [reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=d08f7390caa77eb7c020d62fb16bcdb9-01a6b0bb395e88f874cd84bb78129640) your problem at `-O3`.

Comment: Check the endianness of `uint32/64_t` vs raw `char[]` storage.

Comment: @Yuushi Earlier I was trying to pass `block` as a `char*`, and then casting inside `digitTruncate`. It's left over from that. It also makes it easier to keep track of the number of bytes in case I want 16 for example later.

Comment: @Praetorian Declaring `block` as `uint64_t*` without changing anything else did nothing, but declaring it as a `uint64_t` has it printing numbers now!

Comment: @BrettHale A quick experiment of creating a `uint64_t` with a value of 100, and then printing the a `char*` that points to the same address gave the correct 100 back.

Comment: [Here is a minimal test case](http://ideone.com/hnJ0Ei). If you change the for loop to `i < 3`, the code [prints 5](http://ideone.com/6ch6Hg) as expected. Something with optimizations, but not sure. I think `out = *((uint32_t*)block);` is getting optimized out perhaps?

Comment: @Jesse Oh nice. [Here](http://ideone.com/yYZzPz) it is rewritten using a union for type-punning, which is still UB (for C++) but a common hook for implementations to allow this sort of thing.

Comment: @LucDanton What is UB?

Answer (score 3):

By accessing `block` as a pointer to both `uint64_t` and `uint32_t` you violate the strict alias rules. The compiler is allowed to assume that a particular address is accessed (aliased) as only `char*` and one other type. You're using two  non-`char*` types so all bets are off as to what the compiler's optimizer will do.

Answer (score 1):

Since the value of `out` in the loop is dead, except for the last iteration, and the function has no side effects other than setting `block` (and thus `out`), the compiler is free to eliminate the loop, and just evaluate the last iteration.  Most of the code from that last iteration can be constant folded away, as well.

So you end up with just two consecutive calls to `mytime::cycles()`, which will probably have a difference of 0...

The compiler probably first inlines the call, and then simplifies it down to nothing, rather than noting that it doesn't actually do anything, but the overall effect is the same.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't think it would optimize whole chunks of code out. Wouldn't it be making a false assumption by doing this since `out` needs to change to have the correct output after the loop?

Comment: @chewsocks: You don't show the definition of `mytime::cycles`, so its tough to say what the compiler can figure out from that, but many bits of `block` will always be set to 0 regardless of what the input is.